# Invalid link href in browser?

Tags: html, jsp

I'm writing a href link to Printwriter in my servlet.
But browser displays it as invalid link.

here is my code:

```
       String path = request.getRequestURI();
                 path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
                 path = path + "/open-Account.html.html" ;
                 StringBuffer openAccountLink = new StringBuffer();
                 openAccountLink .append("<a href=").append("\"").append(path).append("\"");
                  openAccountLink .append(">").append("Create an account").append("</a>");
                 out.write("</br>");
                 out.print(openAccountLink .toString());

URL in the log:<a href="/content/pages/location/en_us/user/open-Account.html.html">
```

My logs displays the right above href link but browser complains that its a invalid link..how to overcome this?

Comment: are you sure that there are two .html as in ".html.html" in the address

Comment: How does the browser complain? The only problem is that you have two `.html`'s but that should be perhaps fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you have two extensions in that URL.

What exactly is the browser saying? When does it say it?

Comment: If i directly gives the url path it works..but if I construct dynamically using getRequestURI .its not working...

Comment: Try removing the first "/" before "content".

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your application checking the link before it assigning to href, for example in CQ5 application I am using x-cq-linkchecker="skip" to disable checking this fixed my issue. so in your application please check is there any link checker exist or not.